# How to view HTML file from application explicitly on default browser with version 2.3 in android

Tags: android

I'm doing an android application which I want to view an HTML file from my application data(asset) on default browser.I used below code.Its working fine on some device browsers & not on some devices like Samsung S(with Gingerbread 2.3 version).It shows "Web Page not available... The requested file was not found". I want to view this file only on default browser not webview. How could I do that?

My Code:

```
    Uri myPageUri = Uri.fromFile(new  File(getFilesDirectory(this),"myPage.html"));
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    browserIntent.setClassName("com.android.browser", "com.android.browser.BrowserActivity");
    browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
    browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        browserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    }
    browserIntent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, "com.android.browser");
    browserIntent.setData(myPageUri);

    startActivity(browserIntent);
```

....

```
  public static File getFilesDirectory(Context context) {
    File dir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    if (dir == null) {
        dir = context.getFilesDir();
    }
    return dir;
}
```

Comment: @all Anybody aware about this issue?